# Simple map projection

Tags: java, dictionary, mapping, gis, map-projections

I've a map of 400x400 that approximatively represents an area of 250x250km in that I want to project a GPS coordinate in form of Lat/Lon.

Taking in account that precision is not very important(errors of some km are tolerable) there is any easy formula or algorithm to make the projection and translate to a pixel coordinate? If there is one, what error can I expect?
Or I'm really wrong and there not easy way for the precision that I need?

Notes:

- I readed about PROJ.4 but I prefer to don't use any external library because the program has to run in small devices
- I haven't any calibration data on the map but I can calibrate it myself using an online map.
- From [here](http://www.math.montana.edu/frankw/ccp/cases/Global-Positioning/spherical-coordinates/learn.htm) I documented a little and I know how to convert the lat/lon to x/y/z coordinates. But I don't know how to dial with the Z

Comment: See also gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GIS people will probably stone me for this, but assuming you're not a a high latitude, you could just figure out the lat/lon of diagonal corners of your map to get the bounding box, pick a corner as your origin, take the difference between your GPS coordinate and the origin, then a simple multiplication to scale that to pixels, then draw the point.

I've used this in the past for a map program I was playing with, and I'm at about the 39th parallel. If it doesn't have to be dead accurate, and not too close to a pole (Though, for a 250km square, you'd have to be close to a pole for gross errors to happen), this would be the quickest and the easiest.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, this is done using a [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) and using a [Mercarator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

Here is a good place to [start](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312094930/http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm).

Although it isn't java, there is an open source project called [OpenHeatMap](https://github.com/petewarden/openheatmap) which does this within its source code. This might be a good place to look (specifically the setLatLonViewingArea, setLatLonToXYMatrix, mercatorLatitudeToLatitude in maprender/src/maprender.mxml).

Hope this helps!